# Voltage goes up when using dual graphics cards

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I just inherited a box with an ASUS P5GZ-MX mother board. I have attempted to install two nVidia PCI video cards. I put a 750w power supply in the system to be sure I have enough power. With no extra video cards, the 3.3 v shows normal.

When I put one card in, the 3.3 goes to 3.5-3.6 and flashes red (over voltage) about 30% of the time. When I put the 2nd card in, it goes to 3.73 v and stays red all the time.

Any Ideas why the voltage goes up when I add cards instead of going down?  More Importantly, is this dangerous to the system?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "dumb question" :)

Comment: Just curious, where are you measuring the voltage? Voltage is highest at the source (power plug) and lowest at the destination (load).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that would raise the voltage of the 3.3V rail is being tied to a higher-voltage rail. Check the cards in another system to see if they exhibit the same problem.

Overvoltage can be a problem because it applies more electrical stress to components in the system, which can cause failure.

Comment: +1 Definitely sounds like a power-to-power short. Need to make sure cards are seated properly and aren't touching anything conductive.

Comment: The power supply is a Ultra LSP-750. I removed the two PCI video cards and inserted a TV card in the PCI-E 8 slot and with that card alone the 3.3 went to 3.7+ volts. I suspect that it is just a junk power supply. I know, I know, You get what you pay for. It was a medium priced supply at Comp-USA.

Thanks for your suggestions and ideas.

Comment: I was reading the voltages in the Bios Screen. It was showing all voltages, fan speed, temp etc...

Comment: But a voltage *increase* is bizarre. Normally the voltage is supposed to *decrease* when you increase the load on it.

Comment: I hear ya Ignacio, I know this makes no sense. 
That's why I'm here asking the experts. I am an old programmer, not a hardware guy.